Unable to match modbus address for coils in ESP-IDF
I wrote my own code, derived from the official example from Espressif. From here I understood is not the best code out there, but at the moment I have to live with it.
Here my code:
#ifndef MODBUS_PARAMS_H
#define MODBUS_PARAMS_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t lock:1; // 100001
    uint8_t discrete_input1:1;
    uint8_t discrete_input2:1;
    uint8_t discrete_input3:1;
    uint8_t discrete_input4:1;
    uint8_t discrete_input5:1;
    uint8_t discrete_input6:1;
    uint8_t discrete_input7:1;
} discrete_reg_params_t;
#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t outputs;  // 000001-000008
    uint8_t commands; // 000009-000016
} coil_reg_params_t;
#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct
{
    float battery_voltage; // 300001
    float pressure1; // 300003
    float pressure2; // 300005
    int16_t wifi_rssi; // 300007
    uint64_t r_datetime; // 300008
} input_reg_params_t;
#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct
{
    uint64_t w_datetime; // 400001
    char serial_number[8];
    char id_position[8];
} holding_reg_params_t;
#pragma pack(pop)

extern holding_reg_params_t holding_reg_params;
extern input_reg_params_t input_reg_params;
extern coil_reg_params_t coil_reg_params;
extern discrete_reg_params_t discrete_reg_params;

#endif // MODBUS_PARAMS_H

and:
#include "modbus.h"
#include <mbcontroller.h>

#include "../resources/modbus_params.h"
#include "../utils/settings.h"

#include <esp_err.h>
#include <esp_log.h>
#include <esp_system.h>
#include <esp_wifi.h>
#include <esp_event.h>
#include <esp_log.h>
#include <nvs_flash.h>
#include <esp_netif.h>
#include <esp_mac.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include "../tasks/task_wifi.h"
#include "pump.h"
#include "valves.h"

#define HOLD_OFFSET(field) ((uint16_t)(offsetof(holding_reg_params_t, field) >> 1))
#define INPUT_OFFSET(field) ((uint16_t)(offsetof(input_reg_params_t, field) >> 1))

#define MB_REG_DISCRETE_INPUT_START         (0x0000)
#define MB_REG_COILS_START                  (0x0000)
#define MB_REG_INPUT_START                  (INPUT_OFFSET(battery_voltage)) 
#define MB_REG_HOLDING_START                (HOLD_OFFSET(w_datetime))

#define MB_READ_MASK                        (MB_EVENT_INPUT_REG_RD \
                                                | MB_EVENT_HOLDING_REG_RD \
                                                | MB_EVENT_DISCRETE_RD \
                                                | MB_EVENT_COILS_RD)
#define MB_WRITE_MASK                       (MB_EVENT_HOLDING_REG_WR \
                                                | MB_EVENT_COILS_WR)
#define MB_READ_WRITE_MASK                  (MB_READ_MASK | MB_WRITE_MASK)

static const char *TAG = "MODBUS";

static portMUX_TYPE param_lock = portMUX_INITIALIZER_UNLOCKED;

static void init_reg_data(void)
{
    discrete_reg_params.lock = 0;

    holding_reg_params.w_datetime = 0;

    coil_reg_params.outputs = 0x00;

    input_reg_params.battery_voltage = 0; 
    input_reg_params.pressure1 = 0;
    input_reg_params.pressure2 = 0;
    input_reg_params.wifi_rssi = 0;
}

static void slave_operation_func(void *arg)
{
    mb_param_info_t reg_info; 

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Modbus slave stack initialized.");

    while (1)
    {
        mb_event_group_t event = mbc_slave_check_event(MB_WRITE_MASK);
        if (event & MB_EVENT_HOLDING_REG_WR)
        {
            mbc_slave_get_param_info(&reg_info, MB_PAR_INFO_GET_TOUT);   
            if (reg_info.address == (uint8_t*) &holding_reg_params.w_datetime)
            {
                ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Datetime updated!");
                portENTER_CRITICAL(&param_lock);
                struct timeval tv;
                tv.tv_sec = holding_reg_params.w_datetime;
                tv.tv_usec = 0;
                settimeofday(&tv, NULL);
                portEXIT_CRITICAL(&param_lock);
            }
        }
        else if (event & MB_EVENT_COILS_WR)
        {
            mbc_slave_get_param_info(&reg_info, MB_PAR_INFO_GET_TOUT);
            if (reg_info.address == (uint8_t*) &coil_reg_params.outputs)
            {
                ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Outputs set to %02X", coil_reg_params.outputs);
                Pump_Set((coil_reg_params.outputs & MODBUS_COIL_OUTPUT_PUMP) ? 255 : 0);
                Valves_Set(0, coil_reg_params.outputs & MODBUS_COIL_OUTPUT_VALVE1);
                Valves_Set(1, coil_reg_params.outputs & MODBUS_COIL_OUTPUT_VALVE2);
                Valves_Set(2, coil_reg_params.outputs & MODBUS_COIL_OUTPUT_VALVE3);
                Valves_Set(3, coil_reg_params.outputs & MODBUS_COIL_OUTPUT_VALVE4);
            }
            else if (reg_info.address == (uint8_t*) &coil_reg_params.commands)
            {
                if (coil_reg_params.commands & MODBUS_COIL_COMMAND_SAVE) 
                {
                    Settings_Save();
                    coil_reg_params.commands &= ~MODBUS_COIL_COMMAND_SAVE;
                }
            }
        }

        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
    }
}

esp_err_t init_reg_area(mb_param_type_t type, uint16_t start_offset, void *address, size_t size)
{
    mb_register_area_descriptor_t reg_area; 
    reg_area.type = type;
    reg_area.start_offset = start_offset; 
    reg_area.address = address; 
    reg_area.size = size;
    esp_err_t err = mbc_slave_set_descriptor(reg_area);
    MB_RETURN_ON_FALSE(err == ESP_OK, ESP_ERR_INVALID_STATE, TAG, "mbc_slave_set_descriptor fail, returns(0x%x).", (int) err);
    return err;
}

static esp_err_t slave_init(mb_communication_info_t *comm_info)
{
    void *slave_handler = NULL;

    esp_err_t err = mbc_slave_init_tcp(&slave_handler);
    MB_RETURN_ON_FALSE((err == ESP_OK && slave_handler != NULL), ESP_ERR_INVALID_STATE, TAG, "mb controller initialization fail.");

    comm_info->ip_addr = NULL;
    comm_info->ip_netif_ptr = (void*) Wifi_GetNetif();
    comm_info->slave_uid = MB_SLAVE_ADDR;
    err = mbc_slave_setup((void*)comm_info);
    MB_RETURN_ON_FALSE((err == ESP_OK), ESP_ERR_INVALID_STATE, TAG, "mbc_slave_setup fail, returns(0x%x).", (int)err);

    init_reg_area(MB_PARAM_HOLDING, MB_REG_HOLDING_START, (void*)&holding_reg_params, sizeof(holding_reg_params));
    init_reg_area(MB_PARAM_INPUT, MB_REG_INPUT_START, (void*)&input_reg_params, sizeof(input_reg_params));
    init_reg_area(MB_PARAM_COIL, MB_REG_COILS_START, (void*)&coil_reg_params, sizeof(coil_reg_params));
    init_reg_area(MB_PARAM_DISCRETE, MB_REG_DISCRETE_INPUT_START, (void*)&discrete_reg_params, sizeof(discrete_reg_params));
    init_reg_data();

    err = mbc_slave_start();
    MB_RETURN_ON_FALSE((err == ESP_OK), ESP_ERR_INVALID_STATE, TAG, "mbc_slave_start fail, returns(0x%x).", (int)err);
    vTaskDelay(5);
    return err;
}

static esp_err_t slave_destroy(void)
{
    esp_err_t err = mbc_slave_destroy();
    MB_RETURN_ON_FALSE((err == ESP_OK), ESP_ERR_INVALID_STATE, TAG, "mbc_slave_destroy fail, returns(0x%x).", (int) err);
    return err;
}

void Modbus_Init(void)
{
    mb_communication_info_t comm_info = { 0 };

    comm_info.ip_addr_type = MB_IPV4;
    comm_info.ip_mode = MB_MODE_TCP;
    comm_info.ip_port = MB_TCP_PORT_NUMBER;
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(slave_init(&comm_info));
    slave_operation_func(NULL);
}

void Modbus_Deinit(void)
{
    slave_destroy();
}

I'm able to read/write values using Qt ModbusTool but it does not match the writings to the coil_reg_params.commands registers.
As far as I know, since coils are 1-bit wide in Modbus specifications, I should access my coils in this way:
uint8_t outputs;  // 000001-000008
uint8_t commands; // 000009-000016

Instead, writing from register 000001 to 000016 match to outputs and from 000016 returns BadIllegalDataAddress.
I tried to change the data size to uint16_t and now from 000001 to 000032 is a match with outputs and above if an illegal address.
What is the correct way to define such a memory areas?
I would be more happy if I can use "bool" values, like I did for discrete inputs.
